# Can I compare the text color of a button?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I'm using the line of code below but it doesn't seem to be doing what I'm expecting, which is to find out if the title text color for the button title is green.  However, I'm not getting a compile error, so it must be doing something:

```
if ([sfield1 currentTitleColor] != [UIColor greenColor])
```

Does someone know if there is a way to do this kind of compare?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using -

```
isEqual:
```

But you need to be careful while using it if there is a difference in colour model, then it might fail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "negation".  Since I want not equal to green, I tried doing nothing when it was equal to green and put my operative logic in the else clause.

Comment: have you tried logging [sfield1 currentTitleColor]?Just check what is present there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It turns out that the color was not what I expected it to be, because I'm checking the text color after the button has been tapped and that action changes the color.  Because of that fact, I couldn't end up using this approach, but your answer does work.

Answer (score 1):

try this it may work.,.,.

```
  but=[[UIButton alloc]init];  
 [but setTitle:@"nice" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [but setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [but setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 450, 40, 20)];
 [self.view addSubview:but];

 if (but.titleLabel.textColor==[UIColor blueColor]) 
  {
  NSLog(@"nothing., it is very easy.,.");
  }
```

i am learning,.,.,,.

Answer (score 1):

Take the two colors run them through:

```
   UIColor *color = value;
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
```

Then compare the two strings?
Maybe a little overkill but if all the above don't work this can be a last resort. (I would highly advise trying to figure out why isEqual isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the isEqual method:

```
if ([[sfield1 currentTitleColor] isEqual: [UIColor greenColor]])
```

Now you're just equalling memory addresses, which are, apparently not equal as they are not the exact same object.

Comment: It turns out this approach does work.  It wasn't working for me because I was checking the color after the button had been tapped, and that action changes the color of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `[[sfield1 currentTitleColor] isEqual: [UIColor greenColor]];`

Comment: It turns out this approach does work.  It wasn't working for me because I was checking the color after the button had been tapped, and that action changes the color of the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[yourfeild currentTitleColor] isEqual:[UIColor yourcurrentcolor]];
```

you're just equalling memory addresses, which are, apparently not equal as they are not the exact same object.

Comment: This is very similar to the answer posted by @verhage. Please make sure you do not provide duplicate answers. If you have the same answer, just vote up the similar answer rather than re-posting it.

Comment: Ok, i am new user. It will not be repeat further.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5 & later, `UIColor` provides getters for the HSL and RGB colorsystems, so you could just write a utility function that compares those for two given colors…

Alternatively, have you tried comparing the CIColor properties of the two colors?